# Real-time write to file, C

Tags: c, linux, file

I'm trying to build a file in which I will keep the most important events from the application. I built a function responsible for logging but it does not seem to work as expected. First of all messages do not appear in APPLOG.LOG file during infinite `while()` loop, but only when application is finished. How should I build the function to write information to the file in real time?
I use a lot of *.c files and in each of them I would like to be able to log events. Shouldn't`fLog = fopen(LOG_FILENAME, "w");` be inside the `APLOG(...)` function?
Below is some code responsible for logging.

logging.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TYPE_GENERAL                1
#define TYPE_BINARY                 2
#define TYPE_INFO                   3
#define TYPE_WARNING                4
#define TYPE_ERROR                  5

#define LOG_FILENAME                "APPLOG.LOG"

FILE *fLog;
```

logging.c

```
void APLOG(FILE *fLog, uint32_t type, char *MESSAGE)
{    
    if(fLog == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error open %s FILE!", TRLOG_FILENAME);   
        exit(1);             
    }
    else
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case TYPE_GENERAL:
                fprintf(fLog, "%s %s %s: %s \n",__DATE__, __TIME__, "GENERAL", MESSAGE);
                break;
            case TYPE_BINARY:
                fprintf(fLog, "%s %s %s: %s \n",__DATE__, __TIME__, "BINARY", "ATTEMPTED TO WRITE A BINARY MESSAGE. FUNCTION NOT ACTIVE");
                break;
            case TYPE_INFO:
                fprintf(fLog, "%s %s %s: %s \n",__DATE__, __TIME__, "INFO", MESSAGE);
                break;
            case TYPE_WARNING:
                fprintf(fLog, "%s %s %s: %s \n",__DATE__, __TIME__, "WARINNG", MESSAGE);
                //send warning to external app
                break;
            case TYPE_ERROR:
                fprintf(fLog, "%s %s %s: %s \n",__DATE__, __TIME__, "ERROR", MESSAGE);
                //send raport to app provider
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fLog = fopen(LOG_FILENAME, "w");
    
    APLOG(fLog, TYPE_INFO, "APP HAS BEEN RUNNING. LOGGING STARTED" );

    while()
    {
        //endless while here. If any part of the code does not work, exit the while and report the problem. More APLOG here.
    }

    APLOG(fLog, TYPE_ERROR, "OUT OF WORK. BACK TO EMERGENCY."); 
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `FILE *`-based IO is buffered? Have you tried `fflush()`?

Comment: `__DATE__, __TIME__` This will print the same date and time of _compilation_ of the file on each line of the log file. You want to get _current_ date and time instead, no? `Shouldn'tfLog = fopen(LOG_FILENAME, "w"); be inside the APLOG(...) function?` Do you _want_ it to be there? The answer depends on what semantics do _you_ want your function to have.

Comment: "Shouldn't `fLog = fopen(LOG_FILENAME, "w");` be inside the `APLOG(...)` function?" No, because the file would be destroyed and rewritten with each logged message. If within the function the file should be opened in `"a"` mode.

Answer (score 0):

FILE * is a stream, which means writing to the file is bufferized and the data is actually written when it's the most convenient for the system (to maximize performance).

You could do it a bit more directly with the set of functions that are not using streams: open/close/write/read/... but even with these functions, the writing will be buffered.

With "streamed" access to files (fopen/fprintf/fclose/...), there is a way to actually write on disk all the data that is waiting to be written.. This is the function **fflush**

If you want your application to actually flush its buffer all the time you must use **fflush(fLog);** at the end of APLOG so every fprintf will be followed by a fflush...

Comment: "but even with these functions, the writing will be buffered." Is a bit misleading in this context. There are at least 2 buffers, one in the program that is used by FILE * streams, which is not used by the `write()`/`read()` functions. And there is a disk driver buffer, which will affect both variants and will NOT be flushed with `fflush()`. But other applications can still read the new data, even when the disk driver still buffers it.

Comment: Or in other words: Using the functions `write()`, using `fflush()` immediately after each `fwrite()`/`fprintf()`/... or disabling the FILE * stream buffer with `setvbuf()` and `_IONBF` do all have the same behaviour when it comes to buffering write data. To flush to disk use `fsync()`.